# How to sync a local javascript object with a remote json database (e.g. firebase)

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, database, nosql

I am developing a playlist service. There is a js object storing the playlist on a NodeJS server. Now I want to sync it with a remote json database whenever the js object is modified or periodically sync the data. Is there any tool doing this? Or is there any suggestion for the sync algorithm? The only way I can come up with is to wipe out all data and insert everything again for each sync event, but that looks inefficient.

Comment: Can't you just always read/write to that remote store? Keeping two things in sync is not trivial (unless you know what you are doing™, which most database developers do). So better leave it up to that remote store. If you really need to cache locally, have fun :)

Comment: Well, I think it's more historical reason. I didn't use a database at the beginning. So the lists is stored in js objects locally, I need to refactor my code a lot to transform the local store to remote one. So I'm thinking what if I don't need to modify the local part but just add data sync. That'll be much more easy (hope so). But you're right. Maybe I should consider the regular db read/write ops.